# What is wrong with my implementation to execute tasks using lock routines?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, locking, openmp, gfortran

I implemented a code that takes an array of `function pointers` called `tasks_ready_master`. It contains 20 elements. Each element points to a `subroutine` (task) and to an `integer` representing the state of the task.
In order to execute the tasks, I only need to:

```
call  tasks_ready_master(index_element)%f_ptr(self,var)
```

`var` represents all the variables needed in the computation.
Since I have 20 tasks, I want to use `OpenMP` to parallelize this code.
For example:
If we have 4 `threads` then we will consider 1 `master`, 1 `application master`(controls the states of the tasks) and 2 `workers` executing the tasks. The `master` should assign the tasks to a free `worker`.

So I don't want to have the executions in this order (it can be but I shouldn't impose it) : worker 1 (first task) / worker 2 (second task) / worker 1 (third task) / worker 2 (fourth task) / .. /
I want to use the `lock routines` in order to let the first `worker` not wait for the second one if he finishes his execution.
We can have the executions in this order (for exemple): worker 1 (first task) / worker 2 (second task) / worker 2 (third task) / worker 2 (fourth task) / worker 1 (fifth task) / .. /
The idea is not to wait for the other `worker` to finish his execution.
To do that, at each execution, the `worker` needs to erase (remove) the element(task) from the `array`. I should imperatively use the `lock routines` and avoid the `OMP_BARRIER`.

Here is my implementation:

```
!Thread Application Master (numero 1)
       if (num_thread==1) then
          do ff=5,20 ! 16 tasks 
             if (associated(tasklist_GRAD(ff)%f_ptr) .eqv. .true.) then
                tasks_ready_master(ff) = tasklist_GRAD(ff)
                tasks_ready_master(ff)%state=STATE_READY
             end if
          end do
       end if
       
       !$OMP BARRIER  !!I used this OMP_BARRIER because I had a segmentation fault
       
       if ((num_thread .ne. 0) .and. (num_thread .ne. 1)) then
          do ff=1,nthreads-2
             if (num_thread==ff+1) then
                if (tasks_ready_master(ff+4)%state==STATE_READY) then 
                   tasks_ready_master(ff+4)%state=STATE_RUNNING
                   free_workers_list(ff)=1
                   call  tasks_ready_master(ff+4)%f_ptr(self,var)
                   tasks_ready_master(ff+4)%state=STATE_INACTIVE
                   free_workers_list(ff)=0
                   call erase(5,s,tasks_ready_master)
                end if
             end if
          end do

          do l=nthreads+3,20
             call omp_set_lock(lock)
             do ff=1,nthreads-2
                if (num_thread==ff+1) then 
                   if (free_workers_list(ff)==1) then 
                      call omp_unset_lock(lock)
                   else
                      s=size(tasks_ready_master)
                      if (tasks_ready_master(ff+4)%state==STATE_READY) then
                         free_workers_list(ff)=1
                         call tasks_ready_master(5)%f_ptr(self,var)
                         tasks_ready_master(5)%state=STATE_INACTIVE
                         free_workers_list(ff)=0
                         call erase(5,s,tasks_ready_master)
                      end if
                      call omp_unset_lock(lock)

                   end if
                end if
             end do
          end do
       end if
```

For the declaration and initialization part, I did:

```
    INTEGER ::ff,l
    type(tcb)::self
    type(variables)::var
    integer::s
    !OpenMP variables
    integer::num_thread,nthreads
    integer:: OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM, OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS    
    type(tcb),dimension(20)::tasklist_GRAD,tasks_ready_master
    integer::STATUS=0
    integer,allocatable,dimension(:)::free_workers_list !liste contenant les nums des threads workers 
    !Variables pour gestion des threads 
    INTEGER(KIND=omp_lock_kind), SAVE :: lock

    CALL omp_init_lock (lock)

    !=======================================================================================================================================================
    !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(num_thread,nthreads,ff) &
    !$OMP SHARED(tasklist_GRAD,tasks_ready_master,free_workers_list,s)
    num_thread=OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM() ! le rang du thread 
    nthreads=OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS() ! le nombre de threads
```

For the assignment of the tasks to the array:

```
 !attribution des taches aux listes (20 tasks)
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%f_ptr => u_prime_1 !1
  tasklist_GRAD(2)%f_ptr => u_prime_droite_1 !2
  tasklist_GRAD(3)%f_ptr => u_prime_gauche_1 !3
  tasklist_GRAD(4)%f_ptr => u_grad_x_1 !4
  tasklist_GRAD(5)%f_ptr => u_prime_2 !5
  tasklist_GRAD(6)%f_ptr => taux_ !6
  tasklist_GRAD(7)%f_ptr => u_prime_gauche_2 !7
  tasklist_GRAD(8)%f_ptr => u_prime_droite_2 !8
  tasklist_GRAD(9)%f_ptr => ax_droite_1 !9
  tasklist_GRAD(10)%f_ptr => ax_gauche_1 !10
  tasklist_GRAD(11)%f_ptr => ux_droite_1 !11
  tasklist_GRAD(12)%f_ptr => ux_gauche_1 !12
  tasklist_GRAD(13)%f_ptr => u_grad_x_2 !13
  tasklist_GRAD(14)%f_ptr => u_prime_gauche_3 !14  
  tasklist_GRAD(15)%f_ptr => u_prime_droite_3 !15
  tasklist_GRAD(16)%f_ptr => ax_droite_2 !16
  tasklist_GRAD(17)%f_ptr => ax_gauche_2 !17
  tasklist_GRAD(18)%f_ptr => ux_droite_2 !1
  tasklist_GRAD(19)%f_ptr => ux_gauche_2 !19
  tasklist_GRAD(20)%f_ptr => u_grad_x_3 !20

  do ff=1,20
     tasklist_GRAD(1)%state=STATE_WAITING
  end do

  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%ww_t => ww 
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%pas_t => pas 
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%cpt_t => cpt 
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%nb_element_t => nb_element
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%cpt1_t => cpt1
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%dt_t => dt
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%dx_t => dx 
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%p_element_t => p_element
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%u_prime_t => u_prime 
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%u_prime_moins_t => u_prime_moins
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%u_prime_plus_t => u_prime_plus
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%taux_t => taux
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%grad_x_u_t => grad_x_u 
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%grad_t_u_t => grad_t_u
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%grad_x_f_t => grad_x_f
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%grad_t_f_t => grad_t_f
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%ax_plus_t => ax_plus
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%ax_moins_t => ax_moins 
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%ux_plus_t => ux_plus 
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%ux_moins_t => ux_moins
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%sm_t => sm
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%flux_t => flux 
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%tab0_t => tab0
  tasklist_GRAD(1)%variables%tab_t => tab
```

You can find the whole code on: https://gitlab-sds.insa-cvl.fr/houeslat/stage_hecese/-/blob/master/OpenMP/hecese_OMP/app_management_test.f90.
I am facing a problem since the execution time increased and I feel that I'm executing the tasks not in parallel.

Comment: I'll say both things again. Firstly what you are trying to do non-trivial; I've given up trying to follow it as I have other things to do, and you are hoping somebody here has quite a lot of time to input to this. Secondly to have any hope of making progress we will need a complete code - performance is only debugable by compiling, running and profiling. Repeatedly. Realistically I suspect you are more or less on your own now. However I do wonder why aren't you using OpenMP tasks? They seem a good fit for your description.

Comment: I don't understand the advantage of OpenMP tasks .. my problem is how can the master control the workers and how can he know if they are free in order to give them the tasks which need to be executed .. As I explained in the question, the first worker can execute 4 successive tasks if the other ones are not free .. I don't understand how using locks can help me to find a solution ..